# global scope in nested function

Tags: python-3.x

Why does `global` not work like I think it should in a nested scenario? How can I achieve the same access?

```
a = 0
def outer():
    def inner():
        global a
        a = 100

    print (a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    outer() # 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never actually invoked `inner()` that performs the assignment:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        global a
        a = 100
    inner()  # Invoke it
    print (a)
```

now `100` is printed correctly.